# ng-include template variable not changing on $scope.$watch (no button trigger)?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-include, angularjs-watch

I have a controller 'AController' that has a template variable, $scope.tpl.partialtemplate1 = 'initialcontactlist.html'.

'AController' basically is in charge of an entire page, 'mainpage.html', where we have

```
<div ng-include="tpl.partialtemplate1"></div>
```

On 'mainpage.html', there is a form to add contacts. This form is not part of 'partialtemplate1''s views.

Upon submitting the form, I want the HTML view for 'partialtemplate1' to be reset to what it was on initial page load, because it will then reload the latest list of contacts.

I have tried things like incrementing a variable after each new contact is successfully added, and then having that variable watched and the partialtemplate variable changed.

for example, in 'AController':

```
  $scope.tpl = {};
  $scope.contactcount = 0;
  $scope.contactsignupdata = new Contact();
  $scope.tpl.partialtemplate1 = 'initialcontactlist.html';
  $scope.successmessage = null;


$scope.addcontact = function() {
  $scope.contactsignupdata.$save();

        $scope.successmessage = 'Saved!';

        $scope.contactsignupdata = new Contact();
        $scope.contactcount = $scope.contactcount + 1;
};

 $scope.$watch('contactcount', function(newValue, oldValue) {
         $scope.$apply(function() {
             $scope.tpl.partialtemplate1 = null;
             $scope.tpl.partialtemplate1 = 'initialcontactlist.html';
         });
    /*$scope.partialtemplate1 = 'projecttasklists.html';*/

    });
```

Why isn't the partialtemplate variable getting changed? Yes, the contact gets successfully saved each time - I took care of that with the Rails factory...

Answer (score 1):

Your code sets `partialtemplate1` to `null`, then straight back to `'initialcontactlist.html'`. As far as Angular is concerned, nothing is changed. True bindings are not supported meaning that just because you changed partialtemplate1, doesn't mean it immediately happens or triggers any special events. For this specific scenario, you would have to set partialtemplate1 to null, set a timer, then trigger the change back to 'initialcontactlist.html'

**I do not recommend this by the way**

```
   $scope.$watch('contactcount', function(newValue, oldValue) {
         $scope.$apply(function() {
             $scope.tpl.partialtemplate1 = null;

             $timeout(function() {
                 $scope.tpl.partialtemplate1 = 'initialcontactlist.html';
             }, 1000);
         });

    });
```

**I highly recommend**

Creating an API for Contacts that you can query. That way when a Contact is created, updated, or removed you can handle it yourself in a couple ways:

1. You can requery the data source each time something changes
2. If the API returns data related to the change, you don't need to requery

You should look into creating Angular Services and/or Factories to handle this. In fact it is quite easy to implement if it is a true REST API using [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). If it is not a RESTful resource, you can use [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for custom queries

Comment: I actually do use $resource and have a proper factory, etc. The problem is my form is in a different part of the page than what ng-include covers. Within my ng-include template, I do have another ng-include template that gets modified by clicking  buttons. I just tried what you said and got:Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

Comment: Probably need a longer time on the timer. Or there is an infinite loop somewhere I'm not seeing. Either way, I don't suggest that solution. You need to consider restructuring your app and code. Is there any need for the ng-include? Do you need another controller for the subsection? Pull more logic out to a service?

Comment: I did solve the problem in another way. I used $emit. I will just show my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with $emit.

In the HTML file, upon pressing the submit button for the "Add a contact" form, two events are triggered (separated by the apostrophe button).

```
ng-click="addcontact(contactsignupdata.name);$emit('MyEvent')"
</form>
{{successmessage}}
```

In the controller file:

```
    $scope.successmessage = null;
    $scope.tpl = {};
    $scope.tpl.partialtemplate1 = 'initialcontactlist.html';     

   $scope.addcontact = function(value) {
    $scope.contactsignupdata.$save();

    $scope.successmessage = 'Saved ' + $scope.contactsignupdata.name;

    $scope.contactsignupdata = new Contact();
    };

   $scope.$on('MyEvent', function() {
    $scope.tpl.partialtemplate1 = null;

    $scope.resettofullcontactslist($scope.tpl.partialtemplate1);


});

 $scope.resettofullcontactslist = function(value) {
      $scope.tpl.partialtemplate1 = 'initialcontactlist.html';     
 };
```